# recursive function for floor division

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, division, floor

I am creating a recursive function that essentially operates floor division without using the ' // ' operator. I have figured out the function, but only when input n is positive and I am struggling to figure out how to operate the function when n < d. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

My current code:

```
def quotient( n , d ):

    if (n >= d):
        return quotient(n - d, d) + 1

    else: 
        return n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
def quotient( n , d ):

    if (0<=n<d):
        return 0
    if (n >= d):
        return quotient(n - d, d) + 1
    if n<0:
        return quotient(n + d, d) - 1
```

If `0<=n<d` the quotient is 0, this is the first `if`. If `n` is negative, we handle it in a similar fashion to the positive case, just switch the signs.

Comment: Thank you so much!